# Single Dashboard of multiple Dashboard from Different GitHub repos

Tags: github, project, github-projects

Pre-Conditions

At least have 2 Project Board on GitHub with 2 different Github repos
In my case it is "Dashboard for 3.50 SMP" and "Dashboard for 8.10.0 Kibana"
Both the Dashboard have the same columns

Screen-Shot

[project A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vhof0.png)

[project B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o74eW.png)

I have a requirement of creating single dashboard of multiple Dashboard from Different GitHub repos. Is there any way that can be done without manually copying each and every card.

Combined Project ( under this project I want to move the entire tickets of to-do column from project a and b to show in this project without manually adding in this new project and same goes for other columns e.g. in-progress, in-progress and ready for testing column

[Merged Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNa13.png)